# typescript - generics - reference to parameter from same parameter list

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

Can somebody explain why the following isn't allowed in Typescript?

```
interface Base<T> {
}

interface SomeInterface<First, Second extends Base<First>> {
}
```

For some reason I do not understand, it is not possible to refer to type `First` in `Base<First>`.

The error is: *Constraint of type parameter cannot reference any type parameter from the same parameter list.*

Comment: If an answer was provided, you should really not just read & ignore it, but provide feedback and, if it answered the question fully, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9&referringTitle=Documentation) on breaking changes for 0.9.7, this was introduced to reduce overhead:

> Instead, use constraint arguments that are not in the same argument
>   list, make constraints non-generic, or simply pass 'any' as the
>   parameter to the constraint.
>
> Reason: The added overhead in terms of type-checking, error-reporting,
>   and design complexity did not add enough additional expressiveness to
>   make it worthwhile for 1.0. We may revisit this in future versions of
>   TypeScript.

Your usecase is exactly one of the two mentioned ones in the documentation there.